# Characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to show that converse of the statement: Two 2 by 2 matrices over F which are not scalar matrices are similar if and only if they have the same characteristic polynomial.

Here is my attempt:

If the polynomial has two distinct roots in F, clearly two are similar to the diagonal matrix.

If the polynomial only has a repeated root, then two are similar to the elementary Jordan matrix since these two are not scalar matrices.

If the polynomial doesn't have roots in F, then ..........

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the polynomial doesn't have roots in $F$, then their rational canonical form is the same: the companion matrix of the characteristic polynomial, hence they are similar.